# How to use systemd script

Tags: nginx, flask, systemd, upstart

I am trying to deploy flask app on aws using nginx.I am trying from this tutorial:here is the link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

The problem is he is using upstart script here but ubuntu 16.04 does not support upstart script.What should i do to make it work.Here is the **upstart script**:

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]  
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid user
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin
chdir /home/user/myproject
exec uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
```

Here is **myproject.ini**

```
 [uwsgi]
 module = wsgi

 master = true
 processes = 5

 socket = myproject.sock
 chmod-socket = 660
 vacuum = true
 die-on-term = true
```

As soon as i write:

```
 sudo start myproject
```

it shows error

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 is a version for 16.04. i don't know about deployment to `aws`.

Comment: You can try this other tutorial that uses gunicorn instead of uwsgi: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04. Though it does mention an upstart script for convenience, you can easily bypass it by running gunicorn directly and passing your flask app object like this: `gunicorn --bind unix:app.sock app:app` (this assumes that your script file name is `app`, and your flask variable name is also `app`).